# Перевод римской цифры с помощью Enum

Tags: java, enum, преобразование

Подскажите, как можно перевести римскую цифру, введённую с консоли (I или II или III или IV), которая находится в массиве `strings[0]` через `enum`?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String str1 = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] strings = str1.split(" ");
            String g= strings[0];
           
            //??? чтобы вывести перевод из массива, с помощью enum
            Roma perevod = Roma.III;//????   g
            System.out.println(perevod.getTranslation());
        }
    }
    enum Roma {
        I(1), II(2), III(3), IV(4);
        private int translation;
        Roma(int translation){
            this.translation = translation;
        }
        public int getTranslation() {
            return translation;
        }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! А если не трудно, напишите возможно ли обратно ввести 4 чтобы перевести римскую IV пользуясь enum?

Comment: А вы хотите сделать это посредством этого же `enum`-а?

Comment: Да, это реально или надо что-то придумывать?

Answer (score 1):

Для получения члена `enum`-а по имени служит метод `valueOf()`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Roma one = Roma.valueOf("I");
        Roma two = Roma.valueOf("II");
        Roma three = Roma.valueOf("III");
        Roma four = Roma.valueOf("IV");

        List<Roma> romas = List.of(one, two, three, four);
        List<Integer> numbers = List.of(one.getTranslation(), two.getTranslation(), three.getTranslation(), four.getTranslation());

        System.out.println(romas);
        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
[I, II, III, IV]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

В случае, если не найдётся члена `enum`-а с заданным именем, будет брошено исключение `IllegalArgumentException`.

```
Roma one = Roma.valueOf("hello");
```

Результат:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant Roma.hello
```

---

В соответствии с вашим комментарием (к вопросу) дополняю ответ, как можно при таком `enum`-е получить римскую цифру из обычной.

Не знаю, может быть, можно как-то иначе, но мне с ходу приходит в голову вариант получить все возможные члены `enum`-а посредством метода `values()`, а затем проходиться по полученному массиву и смотреть, у какого члена есть заданный `number`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int number = 4;
        Roma[] romas = Roma.values();
        Roma found = null;
        for (Roma roma : romas) {
            if (roma.getTranslation() == 4) {
                found = roma;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(found);
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
IV
```

Comment: Это я понимаю, мне надо было чтобы из массива вытянуть значение, а оно задаётся в консоле. первый вариант подходит больше. Спасибо.

Comment: Так это я просто для упрощения задачи сделал сканнер от строки, а не от консоли. Вы сделайте так, как у вас было, и всё будет работать. Плюс @Богдан дополнил ответ, как получить римскую цифру по обычной.

Comment: Так оно работает, но с вводом с консоли не хочет, может я что-то не так делаю, не знаю.

Comment: А что вы вводите в консоль и что значит "не работает"? Хоть это уже и другой вопрос, но всё же

Comment: Предположим, вы вводите одну строку, "I II III IV", то есть, римские цифры, разделённые пробелами, а затем жмёте Enter. Тогда эта строка затем разбивается по пробелу `split`-ом, получаете отдельные римские цифры. И подставляете их в те места, где они у меня прописаны в явном виде. То есть, вместо "I", "II" и так далее.

Comment: В консоль я ввожу к примеру 'X + V' нажав энтер в программе переводит римскую цифру в арабскую, производит сложение и выдаёт ответ арабской, теперь чтобы  вывести ответ римской мне нужно преобразовать её обратно в римскую, я не могу подставить переменную в ваше выражение.

Comment: А у вас что, все римские числа расписаны в `enum`-е до бесконечности?) Ведь чтобы сложить X и V понадобится член XV, переменная `translation` которого равна 15. И почему не можете подставить переменную в выражение? Подставляете 5, выдаёт V. Подставляете 10, выдаёт X. Конкатенируете X и V, получаете XV.

Comment: Попробую ещё...

Comment: Да, пошло, спасибо!!! если бы вы не написали,  то я бы искал другое решение, где-то в  первый раз ошибся и не перепроверил. Просто спасибище огромное!!!

Comment: @Богдан отлично, рад, что в итоге всё получилось) Не забывайте про галочку - так сказать, про встроенные средства благодарности на stackoverflow)

Comment: Поставил. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Каждый `enum` получает метод для преобразования строк в значения. [Enum.valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-):

> ... for a particular enum type T, the implicitly declared `public static T valueOf(String)` method on that enum may be used ...

```java
            // ...
            Roma perevod = Roma.valueOf(g);
            // ...
```